# Where not exists in mysql How ignore all id if exist with some condition

Tags: mysql, sql

My question is if ID uses codes `FREE25` , `FREE20` and `FREE10` I want to ignore all IDs those who use codes `FREE25` and `FREE20`.

How ignore all IDs if ID present has codes with `FREE25` , `FREE20`?

```
+------+--------+
| ID   | Code   |
+------+--------+
|    1 | FREE25 |
|    1 | FREE20 |
|    1 | FREE10 |
|    2 | FREE10 |
|    3 | FREE10 |
|    3 | FREE50 |
+------+--------+
```

I want output like

```
+------+
| ID   |
+------+
|    2 | 
|    3 |
+------+
```

Comment: Fine, what have you tried?

Comment: @panther As normally we use NOT IN ('FREE25', 'FREE20') but it's not working

Comment: This should be something along the lines of select distinct id from T where not exists (...)

Comment: @MartinDrautzburg i also use this

SELECT ID FROM camp  WHERE  NOT EXISTS
(SELECT * FROM ashu.camp WHERE CODE IN ('FREE25','FREE20')) ; but it's not given proper result set

Comment: The IDs need to be the same too.

Comment: My question is if ID use FREE25 , FREE20 and FREE10 i want to ignore all ID those who use  FREE25 , FREE20

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use `not exists`

```
select
distinct t1.id from table_name t1
where not exists (
 select 1 from table_name t2
 where t1.id = t2.id
 and t2.code in ('FREE25','FREE20')
);
```